# Split list of strings into list of lists of strings

Tags: string, haskell, dictionary, words

I have a list of strings. I want to split each of the strings on space, e.g. using `words`, resulting in a list of lists of strings. Unfortunately I can't use `map words myList` because map expects [a] -> [b], whereas I want [a] -> [[b]]. How would I go about this?

The other option off the top of my head is a recursive function where I split off the head string from my original list, `words` it and then analyse the result there and then, but I was trying to do it with pre-existing functions and a one-liner.

Comment: I don't understand why `map words` is not what you want.  Can you give an example?

Comment: I was getting an error which appeared to point to `map words` not working; however, after further analysis at the prompting of the answers, I discovered that my initial analysis of the cause of the error was not in fact `map words`. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type signature of 'map' is

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

The type signature of 'words' is

```
words :: String -> [String]
```

Therefore, the type signature of 'map words' is

```
map words :: [String] -> [[String]]
```

Hey, that's exactly what you want! Let's give it a try.

```
map words ["hello world","stack exchange"]
```

outputs:

```
[["hello","world"],["stack","exchange"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand, you can use `map` and `words` to produce such a result:

```
GHCi, version 7.10.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> let { splitWords [] = []; splitWords ws = map words ws }
Prelude> splitWords []
[]
Prelude> splitWords ["first sentence", "second sentence"]
[["first","sentence"],["second","sentence"]]
Prelude>
```

I think the important thing to take away here is just because map expects `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` doesn't mean that `b` has to be the same type as `a`. Here `a` is a String and `b` is a `[String]`

Comment: No need to special case the empty list. We already have `map words [] = []`.